# Implicit interface call function

Tags: go

Looking for some examples to server static files with `net/http` package in Golang, I found the type `Dir` which implements `FileSystem` interface.

Some examples show You can server static files with the following:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp")))
```

What exactly is `http.Dir("/tmp")` ? It looks like a constructor function for `FileSystem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.Dir("/tmp")` is actually a type conversion where you convert the string `/tmp` into the `http.Dir` type. Looking at the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir), you will see that `http.Dir` is actually a string type. Hence, this type conversion works.

In addition, the `http.Dir` type also implements the `func Open(name string) (File, error)` function. Hence, it can be used anywhere where a [`FileSystem`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) interface is used.

You can also check out the [`func ServeFile(w ResponseWriter, r *Request, name string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) function in the `net/http` package.